# Allow the user to call out an element of a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

Is there any way to allow the user to call out an element of a JSON object?

something to the effect of:

```
var jsonobj = {"name":"charlie", "age":"17"};

var ins = document.getElementById('input_box');
var usergen = ins.value;

div.innerHTML = jsonobj.usergen;
```

Comment: `jsonobj.usergen` is undefined. Did you mean `jsonobj[usergen]`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

```
jsonobj[usergen]
```

Also, what you are defining in `jsonobj` isn't JSON... it's just an object literal.  JSON is a string representation of an object that is compatible with JavaScript's object notation.

Comment: The distinction is important since JavaScript's object notation is not fully compatible with JSON

Comment: Damn, yeah my familiarity with the esoteric terminology is complete shit, I originally called it a dict, is that better?, but changed it when I tried to apply the JSON tag and saw that JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation...

Comment: so this implies the extension to subordinate elements json[first][second][third]... ?

Comment: @Peregrine yes.  `{"first": {"second": {"third": "value"}}}`.  You can access `value` via `['first']['second']['third']`

Answer (score 0):

[There's no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) What you have there is simply an "object".

Anyway, the square bracket syntax will do what you want:

```
div.innerHTML = jsonobj[usergen];
```

...bearing in mind that the user may enter a property name that doesn't exist in which case `jsonobj[usergen]` will return `undefined` which will end up being displayed as the string `"undefined"` when you try to put it into your div. You can test for that if you like:

```
if (usergen in jsonobj)
    div.innerHTML = jsonobj[usergen];
else {
    alert("The property '" + usergen + "' does not exist.");
    // OR perhaps
    div.innerHTML = "The property '" + usergen + "' does not exist.";
}
```